# Openshift Apache HTTP Server without Git-Repo

Tags: apache, openshift, static-html

I am about to create a "Test-Dashboard" for our automatic tests.
The test result of one day consists of multiple static html files. These files will be updated daily and the old files will be moved in a folder named with the current date.
The files are stored on a persistent Storage inside my Openshift-Project.

Now I want to mount this storage into an running Apache HTTP Server Pod to make the results accessible but I just find solutions where the files are inside a Git-Repo.
Is there a possibility to create a solution which won't depend on having the files in a Git-Repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deploy an Apache HTTP Server, Nginx or Node Docker image on your Openshift-Project.
There's just no template for this UseCase and therefore you won't find any working solution in your Openshift-Catalog.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my recommendation:

Deploy the default Apache app with the example git repo (https://github.com/openshift/httpd-ex.git).

```
oc new-app httpd-example
```

This gives you an Apache deployment. Now add your persistent volume to the deployment. Then set the environment variable `DOCUMENTROOT` to the full path of your persistent volume

```
oc env dc httpd-example DOCUMENTROOT=<path>
```

This should trigger a redeployment and configure Apache to server all files directly from your persistent volume.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. Since I don't need the whole "git configuration" from the Openshift example catalog, I've choosen a plain HTTP-Server Docker Image (nginx, apache http, node ...). Then I continued just as you described later.